# How to access the elements of a list/tuple in an arbitrary order?

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples, iterable

With Python's slicing operators, one can for instance achieve:

```
a = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
>>> a[0:5:2]
[0, 20, 40]
```

What do I do if I want to access the elements of a list in an arbitrary order? What I want to do is something like this:

```
>>> a([1,0,3,5]) #MATLAB notation!
[10, 0, 30, 50]
```

([I know how to do this with numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html), but if possible, I'd rather not import any packages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use do it as follows:

```
b = [1,0,3,5]
x = [a[i] for i in b]

>>> x
[10, 0, 30, 50]
```

as you said you'd rather not import any packages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), like this

```
from operator import itemgetter
print itemgetter(1, 0, 3, 5)(a)
# (10, 0, 30, 50)
```

You can even store this in a variable and use this later on. For example,

```
custom_picker = itemgetter(1, 0, 3, 5)
custom_picker(a)
```

Comment: This will probably be faster than @sshashank124 's solution because `operator` is implemented in C, so `itemgetter` will likely outperform a Python loop.

Comment: I accepted sshashank124's answer because it doesn't require imports, but this is good to know, thanks! Although one downside is that in order to obtain a list, it seems one would have to write: `list(itemgetter(1, 0, 3, 5)(a))`.

Comment: @andreasdr I don't know what your usecase is, but practically tuples and lists are almost the same (except for the fact that tuples are immutable)

Comment: @andreasdr Also, if you are going to pick values from those particular indexes, in that order, then `itemgetter` would be a better choice.